# Update externalized tikzpicture written in external tex file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

I'm using `pgfplots` and `\tikzexternalize`. I have the following folder structure:

```
tikz/
chapter1/
  chapter1.tex
main.tex
```

In **main.tex** the contents of **chapter1.tex** are included:

```latex
...
\begin{document}
  \include{./chapter1/chapter1}
\end{document}
```

In **chapter1.tex** I have the actual tikzpicture definition:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
  ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If I place the tikzpicture definition in **main.tex** and then change its content, it gets redrawn as expected. However, if the tikzpicture is defined in **chapter1.tex** and I change its content, it doesn't get redrawn and I manually have to delete the related files (md5 hash, output pdf and log files) in order for the compiler to redraw the picture.

Is there a way to solve this issue and have Lua/LaTeX to correctly update tikzpictures defined in included tex files?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to tex.SE. Have you actually tried `\tikzset{external/force remake}`

Comment: @MarkusG., thank you for the suggestion. Wouldn't that command just disable md5 checks and redraw on each compilation? If that's so, I could alternatively use `\tikzexternaldisable` before and `\tikzexternalenable` after the tikzpicture I'm currently editing/redrawing. I'm interested in knowing if there's an automatic check which I'm not aware of, just like it does when the picture is defined in the main tex file.

Comment: That is true, I just thought it might help you debugging.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) From what I understand from your question it sounds like a usual use-case. That is what I use for several years and never had any problems with that. So it would be nice if you could edit your question and propose a [minimal (not) working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we can reproduce your problem.